# How to save selected values from one table column to another table column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, simple-form

I am new to Rails, and trying to learn. In my simple form I have created a drop down select with generated data from a table called professions. This part is working fine, and I can select multiple values. I'm using a mysql database.

When I click the submit button, I need it to save the chosen values to a column called my_professions in another table called users. I can’t figure out how to do this.
I get this error

[image: param is missing or the value is empty: user]

**My form**

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>
<%= collection_select(:f, :professions_id, Profession.where.not(name: nil), :id, :name, {:multiple => true}, {:class=>'js-example-basic-multiple', :id=>'jsmultipleddd'}) %>
<%= f.submit "Save", :class => 'btn blue'  %> 
<% end %>
```

I have tried to add this to the user model

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

has_many :professions
accepts_nested_attributes_for :professions

serialize :my_professions, Array
end
```

And this to the profession model

**profession.rb**

```
class Profession < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
end
```

my params look like this

**registration_steps_controller.rb**

```
def user_params

  params.require(:user).permit(:gender,:practitioner_website, :public_health_insurance, clinic_images: [], professions: [])

end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:gender, :practitioner_website, :public_health_insurance, clinic_images: [], professions: []])
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:gender, :practitioner_website, :public_health_insurance, clinic_images: [], professions: []]) 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by getting rid of `accepts_nested_attributes_for :professions`. You don't need nested attributes for this.

Then get rid of `serialize :my_professions, Array`. [Serialize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) is a legacy hack to store complex data in string columns. You don't need or want this (ever), since associations should be stored in join tables in ActiveRecord - not array columns. That's how AR was designed to work and that's how relational databases where designed to work.

Instead what you want is a join model. Which you can generate with:

```
rails g model user_profession user:belongs_to profession:belongs_to
```

Run the migration. You then setup [the associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) between users and professions:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :user_professions
  has_many :professions, through: :user_professions
end

class Profession < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :user_professions
  has_many :users, through: :user_professions
end
```

Now this lets us associate users with professions by passing `profession_ids`.

In a normal Rails form you would create the input with:

```
<%= f.collection_select :profession_ids, Profession.all, :id, :name, multiple: true ... %>
```

In SimpleForm use [the association](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#associations) helper:

```
<%= f.association :professions, ... %>
```

Then whitelist the correct param:

```
def user_params
  # don't jam this into one super long unreadable line
  params.require(:user)
        .permit(
          :gender, :practitioner_website, :public_health_insurance, 
          clinic_images: [], profession_ids: []
        )
end
```

Comment: Super, thank you very much for a good and detailed answer, appreciate it very much :-)